# Can Visual Assist's find all references find only references to to certain class constructor?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-assist

I have C++ code and VA works nicely but I kind of dont like that when I go to

```
MyClass::MyClass(const std::string& arg);
```

and try to find references it finds references of MyClass, not just this specific ctor. 
Can desired behavior be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this post](http://forums.wholetomato.com/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=10865&SearchTerms=1262) on their forum, it has not been implemented yet.

They cite the increased difficulty in detecting *object construction* vs. *explicit member access*.

Comment: Situation unchanged in 2017: https://forums.wholetomato.com/forum/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=13982

Answer (score 4):

Although this functionality still not available in VS2013 SP3 there exists a workaround. Some may consider it a huck but what works for me is to change constructor signature (by introducing additional unused argument) and recompiling entire solution. Let compilation errors point out all invocations. No VA is needed.